# Get total memory usage per node in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I want to query the total memory usage per node in the last week.

Here's the query I am using:

```
sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container_name!="POD"}) by (node)
```

Interestingly, the numbers returned are larger than the physical memory of the nodes.

I am using m5.large EC2 instances(2core, 8GB ram) for all my kubernetes nodes.

What would be the correct query to get total memory per node?

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the best approximation for example according to [this blogpost](https://www.bwplotka.dev/2019/golang-memory-monitoring/). The issue is that even depending on the software the respective container is running (Python, Golang, etc.) the way to measure the "real" memory usage differs.

But from what I understand `container_memory_working_set_bytes` is the best choice for getting data about individual containers.